How do I determine the cause of datastage stopping without an error while performing a scheduled task?
I perform a regularly scheduled task every day, but suddenly the scheduled task runs but does not progress and does not finish.
How do I find out what the cause is?
Execution environment
datastage 11.7.1.1
HP unix
Maintenance personnel reviewed it but found no results.
